# php mssql select * is not working

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error

```
No data! (sqlJadual)
```

From this query

```
mssql_query("SELECT * 
             from tblstatusjadual 
             where idjadual like '1%' and 
                   tahun='2011' 
             order by idjadual") or die('No data! (sqlJadual)');
```

But, when i change it to

```
mssql_query("SELECT idjadual,status 
             from tblstatusjadual 
             where idjadual like '1%' and 
             tahun='2011' 
             order by idjadual") or die('No data! (sqlJadual)');
```

it works fine.

it's okay if I only select from 2 fields, but when I want to select more than 15 fields the query become long and confusing.

my question is mssql does not support select * in their query?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a `Text` field in your table? This problem occurred to me when I tried to `SELECT *` on a table containing a `Text` column with a blank string. I fixed it changing the data type of that column to varchar. And my column had blank strings as one of the values which was why the `SELECT *` was failing...

Comment: Go into your MYSQL database and try pasting the sql query directly into the query search on there. If it has results then there is something wrong with the mssql_query function. From visually looking at it, your query is correct. Select * gets all rows.

Comment: @BrandenStilgarSueper: I assume you meant MSSQL rather than MYSQL :-) And select * gets all _columns,_ not rows.

Comment: Use `die(mssql_get_last_message())` for better debugging.

Comment: @verisimilitude: when I use die(mssql_get_last_message()) this is the error `Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.`

Comment: @verisimilitude: you are right. I change all Text to varchar and that solve my problem. TQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm mentioning my comment as an answer here 'cause it helped you and the next time anyone visits/faces a similar kind of situation, he/she may refer this (instead of scanning the whole string of the above comments' series).

If you issue a `SELECT *` against an `MSSQL` table and your table contains a `TEXT` column with a blank string, you either

1) Change the datatype of that column to `varchar` 
2) Reset the value of the column from blank string to `NULL`.

to make the `SELECT *` work.

(On another note, I'll recommend instead of using `SELECT *`, you include only those columns in your query which you really require.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount of columns and their types. It may be that (for example) one of the column types is a BLOB and the driver is ensuring it has 2GB available in the row data structure for holding it (I've seen this before in some badly written JDBC drivers).

Best way to check for that is to gradually add the other columns (other than `schedule` and `year`) to the second query until it fails. That will probably tell you the errant column, if there is one.

Also, change your `die` statement to something like:

```
die(mssql_get_last_message())
```

so you can hopefully see what the failure message is.

And, based on your response to that:

> Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

It looks like a mismatch of capabilities between your database and the libraries you're using to access it.

Since Unicode is generally accepted as a *good* thing, I'd say stick with that, and see if there's a later version of MSSQL (or the underlying ODBC drivers) which can handle it.

[This page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) also has some advice which may address your problem:

---

When you got this error message:
    "Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot
     be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC
     version 3.7 or earlier."

In /etc/freetds/freetds.conf add these two lines (last two):

```
[global]
;tds version = 4.2
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

You can edit "charset" in php.ini too (but you don't need if you did it previously in freetds.conf):

```
; Specify client character set..
; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used
; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
mssql.charset = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: I will try this method and will be back with the results.